# Drupal7 rename domain cannot login

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a website that was at `www.somedomain.com/sub/drupal7` and all was working well.
I purchased a new domain for the site `www.newdomain.com`
I setup this with my hosting provider as an addon domain pointing to `/public_html/sub/drupal7`

I can access the site using the new domain and it looks ok, but I am unable to login using the new URL.  I can still login using the old URL. I tried modifying `base_url` with no success.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you probably have a wrong `$cookie_domain` variable in your settings.php file.

Edit `sites/default/settings.php` file, and near line 325 - 330, there should be a $cookie_domain that you can change it to `.newdomain.com` (note the prefixing `.` in the domain).